# Xamarin - push notification - trigger for update data from server

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms

Im new in mobile development. Now I write a little app.

User login in app
see list view of data from server. when I add something in server i send push to mobile and update data

Right now - i have Droid app that use this component(https://components.xamarin.com/view/gcmclient/) and receive messages
(c# console app for test ) -- all its work

Now question is - when i handle push from server - how to call method for update list view (this logic located in PCL and handle push located in droid app

P.S I still looking for good tutorial for iOS Push notification. Can somebody give me link?
P.S2 - if its possible use GCM for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call back into your PCL, either by [Dependency Injection](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17368/dependency-injection) or some other method.

PS: GCM for iOS is here: https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiosgcm